# In PHP, what corresponds to mysql.connect_timeout in MySQLi?

Tags: php, timeout, connection, mysqli

We recently ported some code we have to use PHP's MySQLi extension instead of the regular mysql. This code connects to a database that occasionally might not be responding, so we set this variable on PHP.ini:

mysql.connect_timeout = 3

That way if it takes more than 3 seconds to connect to that database, it simply gives up. However this doesn't seem to work for MySQLi. What would be the corresponding setting for MySQLi?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` as reported [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php).

Here's a small example from [this thread](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43866#1200592484):

```
class mysqli2 extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct( $host, $user, $pass, $db, $port=3306 )
    {
        parent::init();
        parent::options( MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
        parent::real_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db, $port );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For a correct answer, though you should note that your code is taken straight from [this bug page](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43866).

Comment: Yes, you can find a huge number of examples into the docs by the way, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php for example.